# Conditional statement in yq parser for updating script

Tags: yaml, jq, yq

I m trying to replace a string value in a yaml file and I m not able to get the `if` working.

YAML file

```yaml
apiVersion: kots.io/v1beta1
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: enterprise
spec:
  groups:
    - name: api_authorization
      title: API Authorization
      items:
        - name: api_key
          title: API Key
          type: password
          required: true
        - name: workspace_id
          title: Workspace ID
          type: text
          required: true
    - name: deep_learning
      title: Deep Learning
      description: Deep Learning Service Options
      items:
        - name: triton_release_options
          title: Release Options
          type: heading
        - name: triton_release_version
          title: Triton Release Version
          type: text
          default: "release-v308" ## Shoudl be updated when the triton release is true
          required: true
        - name: tracker_release_version
          title: Tracker Version
          type: text
          default: "release-v308" ## Shoudl be updated when the tracker is being build as part of the component
          required: true
```

I have tried the following with no luck

```bash
yq e '
   .spec.groups[] |=
      if .name == "deep_learning" then
         .items[] |
         select( .name == "triton_release_version" ) |
         .default = "new_release_version"
      else
         .
      end
' config.yaml
```

```bash
yq e '
   .spec.groups[] |
   select(.name == "deep_learning") |
   .items[] |
   select( .name == "triton_release_version" ) |
   .default = "new_release_version"
' config.yaml
```

I am able to update, but then i m losing the whole yaml file content if i m not using the if condition. With the if I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator precedence is important. You can force order of evaluation by parenthesizing:

```
yq e '(
  .spec.groups[]
  | select(.name == "deep_learning")
  | .items[]
  | select(.name == "triton_release_version")
  | .default
) = "new_release_version"' config.yaml
```

First select the items you want to update (`…[] | select(…) | …`), then update them (`… = "new_release_version"`).

An alternative way of writing the program is:

```
yq e '(
  .spec.groups[]
  | select(.name == "deep_learning").items[]
  | select(.name == "triton_release_version")
).default = "new_release_version"' config.yaml
```

With [mikefarah's `yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you get:

```yaml
apiVersion: kots.io/v1beta1
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: enterprise
spec:
  groups:
    - name: api_authorization
      title: API Authorization
      items:
        - name: api_key
          title: API Key
          type: password
          required: true
        - name: workspace_id
          title: Workspace ID
          type: text
          required: true
    - name: deep_learning
      title: Deep Learning
      description: Deep Learning Service Options
      items:
        - name: triton_release_options
          title: Release Options
          type: heading
        - name: triton_release_version
          title: Triton Release Version
          type: text
          default: "new_release_version" ## Shoudl be updated when the triton release is true
          required: true
        - name: tracker_release_version
          title: Tracker Version
          type: text
          default: "release-v308" ## Shoudl be updated when the tracker is being build as part of the component
          required: true
```

Comment: @ikegami yes, but `|=` vs `=` doesn't really make a difference if the RHS is a constant value. My first example is already written as `(… | .default) =` and not `(…).default =`

Comment: oh yeah, I kinda forgot about the first solution you posted (`( ... | .default ) = ...`) when I got weird out by `( ... ).default`.